# Emacs Prelude: Background Color

Tags: emacs, emacs-prelude

I installed the Emacs Prelude as suggested in https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude . I find the background-color grey of the Zenburn theme to be disturbing. I wish to change the background-color to black. I tried (set-background-color "black") ,but it is not working. The background-color still remains grey. Can someone help on how to fix this ?

Comment: you will get more help if you ask that question on [super user](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you didn't eval `(set-background-color "black")` (or didn't restart Emacs), since it worked just fine when I tested it with Prelude.

Placing the code in `personal.el` (as mentioned in the README) will work as well.

Btw, if you don't like Zenburn you might try a different theme, rather than playing its colours. You can see a list of available themes with `M-x load-theme`. There are details about this in the README as well.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to do this is to edit `.emacs.d/init.el` and add the following:

```
(disable-theme 'zenburn)
```

This will give you a "fresh start" with default color settings. You are then free to change the colors as you wish.

If you like a black background, you might want to install the popular [Cyberpunk theme](https://github.com/n3mo/cyberpunk-theme.el).

`M-x package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd>
`cyberpunk theme`<kbd>RET</kbd>